# Ionic3 : JSON to an array

Tags: jquery, angularjs, typescript, laravel-5, ionic3

I'm trying to convert a JSON from an laravel API into an array on Ionic 3

Here is my json :

[image: output of the console.log]

```
 Object {id_oiseau: 1, 
    nom_commun: "Hirondelle", 
    lieu_signalement: "Foret", 
    date_signalement: "2017-05-16", 
    condition_signalement: "Aile coincee sous branche"…}
    condition_signalement:"Aile coincee sous branche"
    date_reception:"2017-05-16"
    date_renvoi:"2017-05-02"
    date_signalement:"2017-05-16"
    descriptif_etat:"Aile cassee"
    etat_actuel:"En attente de livraison"
    id_acteur:1
    id_adherent_lpo:1
    id_local_lpo:1
    id_oiseau:1
    id_oiseau_dico:1
    id_statut_oiseau:1
    image:"bird-profil.jpg"
    immatriculation:"EZ654ERRZ"
    lieu_signalement:"Foret"
    nom_codifie:"HIRON-NANT-4949845"
    nom_commun:"Hirondelle"
    pays:"France"
```

Here is the provider to receive the JSON for my Ionic app :

```
export class BirdService {

    returnedData;
    headers: any;
    options: any;

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }

    getRemoteData(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('http://extranet.local/api/v1/bird/1', this.headers).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Here is the function to convert the JSON :

```
 export class HistoryPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public serviceOne: BirdService) {}

    ionViewDidLoad() {

        this.serviceOne.getRemoteData().subscribe(
            data => {
                let list: History[] = data;
                console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work because the JSON file stay in JSON "Object {.. : .. , .. : ..}"

I tried with parseJSON with Jquery but i had "Cannot read property 'parseJSON' of undefined"

```
   import { jQuery } from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-History',
  templateUrl: 'History.html'
})

export class HistoryPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public serviceOne: BirdService) {}

    ionViewDidLoad() {

        this.serviceOne.getRemoteData().subscribe(
            data => {
                var History = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(History);
        });
    }
}
```

Also i used Angular with fromJson but Ionic can't find the name "angular"

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { jQuery } from 'jquery';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-History',
  templateUrl: 'History.html'
})

export class HistoryPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public serviceOne: BirdService) {}

    ionViewDidLoad() {

        this.serviceOne.getRemoteData().subscribe(
            data => {
                var History = angular.fromJson(data);
                console.log(History);
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: what is the output for `console.log(data)`?

Comment: I just edited with the output

Comment: can you add the text instead of a picture please?

Comment: No problem, it's done

Comment: Oh dear.. _you dont have to do this at all_..Will add an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse()` method.

You will not need to import any other library for parsing.

Your code should look like below:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

        this.serviceOne.getRemoteData().subscribe(
            data => {
                var History = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(History);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but there is an error : Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: That means your JSON is invalid. Please make sure your JSON is valid. Then only parse functions will work on it.

Comment: I added the JSON on my post, i think my JSON is ok

Comment: If that "Object" bit is included in your raw json it shouldn't be. If that's from console.log then you've logged an object and not the json string. Might need to log/parse data[0] from what I can see.

Comment: @rory_za OP is trying parsing twice..thats the issue

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to parse the json in `subscribe`. **This is because you are doing it in `map` function.** `map(res => res.json())`

```
            let list: History[] = data;
```

This is not working because your data is an object and not an array here.

Just do:

```
       var history = data;
```

you can get content from the object like so:

```
  console.log(history.nom_commun);
```

Comment: Okay so can i just use this way to use my datas in another page with angular like that : *ngFor="let h of History; let i=index"  <p>{{h.nom_commun}}</p> ?

Comment: you are not getting an array..but a single object which wont work in a for loop..if you are expecting an array maybe check server side..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again but i found another way,

i did a

```
History.push(data);
```

So it's an object in an array, my system with angular to use datas seem to work well with this.